# select data from table based on CURTIME() being near entries in a time field

Tags: mysql

I tried:

```
 `SELECT name
    FROM students
    WHERE time BETWEEN '16:20:00' AND '16:45:00'
    AND day = 'Wed'`
```

but got no results and actually I'd rather just have results from entries near CURTIME, like 15 mins before and 15 mins after.
This is for class attendance management.  I basically want to show the next class coming and have a window of time to select who has actually showed up for class.

Comment: Ah, I suppose I should've written NOW() instead of CURTIME()

Comment: check out 'INTERVAL' in mysql it will let you add 15 minutes to NOW

Comment: It needs to be 'around' the class time, though.  For example, students starts showing up a little before the class up to around 15 minutes after.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below query works for you

```
 `SELECT name
        FROM students
        WHERE time BETWEEN CURTIME() AND ADDTIME(CURTIME(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
        AND day = 'Wed'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT name
    FROM students
    WHERE time BETWEEN (NOW(), INTERVAL -15 MINUTE) AND (NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
    AND day = 'Wed'
```